# What is the relationship between the Kano Model and Quality Function Deployment?

Tags: quality, customer-satisfaction

I've read a bit about the [Kano Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kano_model), and seen pictures, etc:
[image: kano model]

but how is this connected to the idea of [Quality Function Deployment](http://www.qfdi.org/).  How do you integrate the ideas behind the Kano model into QFD?

**EDIT:**

Based on Marc's comment, I would say the the 'bottom line' for this question is how to use Kano to make the feature selection in QFD (it's output) more approachable to people who don't know anything about QFD.

Comment: Are you sure that they're related?

Comment: Is your bottom line in the question improved customer satisfaction or an improved process for feature selection (that should translate into improved satisfaction)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To some point both Kano model and QFD deals with the same area which is sorting out which features are must-haves and which are nice-to-haves. Both are tools which should help product managers/product owners to prioritize features and organize product development.

However Kano model leaves us with just a few buckets of where we can put features (Attractive, One-Dimensional, Must-Be, Indifferent, Reverse) leaving product manager or other decision-maker to make their own call which feature is which.

QFD helps product manager to decide how important specific features are putting them against specific project-related criteria and attaching weights to them. The outcome should be similar as the one from Kano model - a prioritized list of features pointing which cause delight and which causes disguise.

QFD delivers more detailed scenario and bases less on product manager's experience and subject matter expertise.

Also sometimes Kano model is used to support decisions in QFD when the latter doesn't deliver clear answer how to prioritize features, which may happen depending on chosen criteria used in QFD.